# Is it possible to fill polygon with pattern using Fabric.js?

Tags: design-patterns, canvas, svg, fill, fabricjs

I was draw polygon object in canvas of pattern image.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL("http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/album_artwork/t2-7.jpg", function(img) {

    img.scaleToWidth(100).set({
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top'
    });

    var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.add(img);

    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: function() {
        patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
          width: img.getWidth() + 0,
          height: img.getHeight() + 0
        });
        return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
      },
      repeat: 'repeat'
    });

    canvas.add(new fabric.Polygon([
      {x: 185, y: 0},
      {x: 250, y: 100},
      {x: 385, y: 170},
      {x: 0, y: 245} ], {
        left: 220,
        top: 200,
        angle: -30,
        fill: pattern
      }));
});
```

I found this source here.

http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns/

But i want to fill in polygon object as SVG type file.

Is it possible ???

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

just  replace:
    patternSourceCanvas.add(img);

with:
    patternSourceCanvas.add(yourShape);

yourShape in the above code may be svg or any simple shapes or whatever,they will be used as the patterns to fill your polygon.